# Can strtotime handle fractions?

Tags: php, strtotime

`date('m/d/Y', strtotime('-1.5 years'))` returns, for today (June 18, 2012), `06/18/2017`.

Why is this, and is there any way to get strtotime to handle fractional years? It seems to be changing "-1.5" to "+5".

Edit: And so you know, this is on PHP 5.1, so the newer date functions aren't available.

Answer (score 4):

Your best solution might be to convert it into months. So `1.5 years` becomes `18 months` which will work.

Comment: Yeah, I was just thinking that, `floor($years * 12)` or something like that. Still, I'm curious, why does it break?

Comment: Was in the process ow writing 'use months' too.

Answer (score 2):

Bug report https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62353&edit=3 has been opened for this issue.

There is a library called timelib which contains all the time functions. It appears as if there is an issue with the conversion of the relative time to timestamp.

The following is the function which creates the relative time:

```
static void timelib_set_relative(char **ptr, timelib_sll amount, int behavior, Scanner *s)
{
    const timelib_relunit* relunit;

    if (!(relunit = timelib_lookup_relunit(ptr))) {
            return;
    }

    switch (relunit->unit) {
            case TIMELIB_SECOND: s->time->relative.s += amount * relunit->multiplier; break;
            case TIMELIB_MINUTE: s->time->relative.i += amount * relunit->multiplier; break;
            case TIMELIB_HOUR:   s->time->relative.h += amount * relunit->multiplier; break;
            case TIMELIB_DAY:    s->time->relative.d += amount * relunit->multiplier; break;
            case TIMELIB_MONTH:  s->time->relative.m += amount * relunit->multiplier; break;
            case TIMELIB_YEAR:   s->time->relative.y += amount * relunit->multiplier; break;

            case TIMELIB_WEEKDAY:
                    TIMELIB_HAVE_WEEKDAY_RELATIVE();
                    TIMELIB_UNHAVE_TIME();
                    s->time->relative.d += (amount > 0 ? amount - 1 : amount) * 7;
                    s->time->relative.weekday = relunit->multiplier;
                    s->time->relative.weekday_behavior = behavior;
                    break;

            case TIMELIB_SPECIAL:
                    TIMELIB_HAVE_SPECIAL_RELATIVE();
                    TIMELIB_UNHAVE_TIME();
                    s->time->relative.special.type = relunit->multiplier;
                    s->time->relative.special.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

**Note:** This bug also causes the same issue that turns:

```
echo strtotime("1.5 days ago");
```

Into -5 days, -5 hours, instead of the desired -1 day and 12 hours (relative).